# How can I run CMD processes in C# without being administrator?

Tags: c#, api, cmd, command-line-interface

I need to run some apps via CMD processes in C# but my application can't launch with administrator rights, only standard user rights.

This is the string I'm using:

```
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = eplanPath+ " /Quiet /Auto /NoLoadWorkspace /NoSplash /Frame:0 RegisterScript /SCRIPTFILE:\"" + scriptPath + "\"";
```

If I run my app in visual studio it works while if I install it in Windows with manifest set as "As Invoker" it won't run.

Thanks, any hel is appreciated.

Comment: What is the differences between running in VS and running in Windows?  I suspect there is something different if the path.

Comment: I think VS runs the app with admin privileges anyway

Comment: No it doesn't in VS.  It will if you run the exe file without VS.

Comment: Well, if I run my app in visual studio the command line task executes succesfully. If I run the same files outside visual studio the command line task fails. I don't know what this could be

Comment: When running in VS any dlls are in the same bin folder as the executable.  When an application fails outside VS it is one of two reasons 1) The dlls are not in same folder as the executables 2) You did not build both the debug and release versions.  Inside VS you are running one executable (debug/release) while outside VS you are running the other.  Check the date of executables to make sure the one you are suing outside VS is current.

Comment: Hi, I checked and I was running the same dll. I always compile both release and debug

Comment: I think that if VS is run in admin mode the apps are also run in admin mode. The problem is that I have a cmd task that will run in admin mode and won't run as standard user mode. It's a simple open application via CMD and I can't sort out how to make it work with standard permissions

Comment: You need with Admin privilege set the executable to Run As Admin (right click executable)  level get upgraded when anybody runs to Admin.  Setting Run As Invoker doesn't allow to upgrade.  See : https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20161117-00/?p=94735&force_isolation=true

Comment: I have found a better way to expose my situation. My application takes an XML input and doesn stuff based on it (for example opening other apps, like a CAD). I can give the XML input in the GUI or via cmd. If I open my app as standard user and execute the xml it works. If I launch my app via standard cmd with xml path parameter it doesnt work in standard privileges but wants elevated privilegs.

Comment: Are you running inside VS or outside?

Comment: outside visual studio

Comment: So only difference between working and non working are parameters on the command line?

Comment: Yes, the same function called from gui works, if I call it from cmd it doesnt work. If I run the debug cmd line in visual studio it works

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with the c# project.  The issue is the parameters you are passing the API.  You need to get the parameters working in the command line before you try to run your c# code.

Comment: In command line the parameters already work if run from administrator cmd

Comment: VS doesn't automatically Run As admin.  You have to right click VS shortcut and select Run Admin.  A Net exe will run as admin, just not inside VS.